# How to send an email from different domains

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am creating an application in which the user should be able to send some reports via email. I need the user to be able to specify his/her email address and for the program to set the necessary properties. My code works when the user uses a gmail account. This is part of the code:

```
final String password = "password";
                        Properties props = new Properties();
                        //gmail
                        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
                        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                            }
                        });
```

The above works. When I try sending from a GoDaddy hosted email I get a problem. I use the following code for the goDaddy email:

```
final String password = "password";
                        Properties props = new Properties();
                        //GoDaddy
                        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtpout.secureserver.net");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "80");
                        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                            }
                        });
```

When I try the above and go to the destination email I don't find anything, but when i check the inbox of the GoDaddy email which is supposed to be the sender email, I find a Mail Delivery System message in the inbox when the following content:
    (Return Code 550] sid: PwwN1o00B0bi6P901 :: 5.7.1 more information. cm5si19503077pac.22 - gsmtp).
Can someone please tell me what the problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most mail servers are not going to let you send email with any arbitrary From address.  If they did, they would be used for spam, phishing, etc.  You have a few choices...

1. Find a service that will let you do this.  Good luck with that!
2. Run your own mail server.  A lot of work, obviously.
3. Ask the user for all the login information for their own mail server, and send the message as them through their own mail server.  Users probably won't like this.
4. Send the reports as a user associated with your application, not as the end user.

Comment: I do have the users access credentials and the SMTP host and port but it's not working with the godaddy email.

Comment: You're connecting to the user's mail server (which happens to be godaddy), you're logging in with the user's username and password, and all that works, but it fails when you try to send a message with a From header of that user?  Show me; post the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: @user3245747, there are payed services like sendgrid, mailchimp, etc. that would allow you to register some email addresses to be able to send `as` them. Other than that, Bill's answer pretty much covers it. Also nowadays sending is also protected by `SPF` and `dmarc` to protect from the "own mail server" option and send them directly to spam or outright reject them.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the Return Code 550. This return code usually means that the server was unable to deliver the mail as the inbox it was trying to send to does not exist. I would figure out what causes the error code when using GoDaddy and also try your code with different email providers.

http://www.serversmtp.com/en/error-550

Comment: I don't think the problem is from the inbox because when I send the same email from Gmail or yahoo mail to the same receipiant it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

From [Various SMTP error codes explained](http://support.mailhostbox.com/email-administrators-guide/error-codes) it is one of the following:

```
550 5.7.1 : Helo command rejected: You aren't localhost.
550 5.7.1 : Helo command rejected: You aren't localhost.localdomain.
550 5.7.1 : Helo command rejected: You are not me
Our servers do not accept SMTP HELO command as HELO localhost or HELO localhost.localdomain or HELO . We accept HELO from a valid Domain Name or your computer name which is other than your domain name. Please check with your ISP or Mail administrator for this issue.

550 5.7.1 Service unavailable; client [a.b.c.d] blocked using rbl.mailhostbox.com
rbl.mailhostbox.com is an inhouse RBL zone which we use to protect our services from inbound attacks. If you encounter any of the above messages, you can whitelist the IP using http://whitelist.mailhostbox.com/
To avoid misuse of this feature, an IP is allowed to be white-listed only a defined number of times. If you face any issues feel free to contact our support helpdesk with the details.
```